# how to choose what you want to scan form a file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am trying to scan from proc/stat using `fscanf`. 
I want to get some info but not all, how do I declare the info I want it to scan or should I just declare every single info and scan it all, but I really dont think this is the right way to do it.

For example: I scan with

```
fscanf ("%d %s %c %d %d %d %d %d  %u) %lu( %lu %lu %lu %lu)
```

so I want everything but not the `%LU` that I keep it out. How can this be written?

Comment: actually its not only that lu that I dont want , I am trying to get these info from the proc ... 

State of the process.
The PID of the parent.
Priority.
The nice value.
Real­time  scheduling priority.
CPU number last executed on.
Virtual memory size in bytes.
Total program size in pages.
Resident Set Size (RSS) in bytes.
Resident Set Size (RSS): number of pages the process has in real memory in 
pages.
Text (code) size in pages.
Data + stack size in pages.
Page table entries size in KB.
Size of data in KB.
Size of stack in KB.
Size of text segment KB.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in a comment, you can use the asterisk to discard the input. From the `scanf` family of functions [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: scanf()
>                 reads input as directed by the conversion specification, but
>                 discards the input.  No corresponding pointer argument is
>                 required, and this specification is not included in the count
>                 of successful assignments returned by scanf().

And an example using the `scanf` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;

    scanf("%d %*d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("A: %d\nB: %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

And if you input "1 2 3", it will output "A: 1 B: 3"

You can do the same thing with **fscanf** and discard as many fields as necessary.